# why we need federationmetadata in relying party? How to manage RP federation Metadata for different enviorment?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, adfs, ws-federation

I created Federation Metadata using FedUtil tool on local, but on adfs server i did not use that federationmetadata for autoclaims I added claims manually.

Now I want to deploy my changes to other enviorment, Can anyone please tell what is the use of FederationMetadata in RP? and how it differs in different enviorment?

The adfs fed-Metadata which I used to configure local RP is having different X509 and other cryptic tags which are different in other adfs federation metadata? Why?  Basically what is the use of it and when it come into the picture?

Note: I am using VSTS 2010 asp.net C#, WIF 3.5 and adfs 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RP metadata for WS-Fed is just a nice-to-have. You can use it to configure the RP on ADFS by importing the metadata but you can do it just as easily by doing it manually. Basically it just contains the entityID and the endpoint.

RP on WS-Fed doesn't use a certificate (unless you chose the encrypt RP claims option).

If you want to hook up the RP to another ADFS just re-import the RP metadata on the new box or do it manually.

Each token minted by ADFS is signed and each ADFS has a different signing certificate which is reflected in the metadata.

Comment: I agree of course with nzpcmad. Metadata is there to make configuration easier. RP configuration (in web.config) contains its own RP specific parameters: EndPoint and EntityID (they normally hardly change in production systems). And the RP web.config also contains the EndPoint, cert and ID of the ADFS server. Especially the ADFS cert may change regularly. There were several utilities to update RP configurations. They all had their pros and contras. Very often the contras were too serious. That is why almost everybody does it "by hand".

Comment: The utility you were talking about also generates the RP metadata (if I remember correctly about this now 5 year old version). That is not such a good idea :-). It should be generated by the RP on request from its own configuration. The WSFAM has all that in memory so there are several samples of HttpHandlers and MVC code that generate the metadata on request. If you want to sign it (which is not super essential if fetched over https), then the RP would need a signing certificate, just for its metadata..